# Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '57x57' pixels

Tags: ios, upload, icons, app-store, package

I was trying to update my app in Appstore and I have started to receive this failure message. I checked over the internet for any solution, but none of them work. I have not changed my icons so this failure should not appear at all.

I have checked the plist file, but always the same issue. The bundle is theoretically missing two icons 57x57 and 72x72 sizes.

Renamed icons and setup the whole icons package in the project, still the same issue.

Comment: Hi, I have figured out the issue and I think it is not a duplications of the problem you have mentioned. I had all the files and all the plist entries as well. The 57 and 72 size icons are for the lower IOS versions. the 120 is for the iOS7, so once it introduced it was an issue if somebody did not add these new recommended icons. My problem was that between to AppStore submission this failure message appeared without changing anything on the icon structure. Finally it turned out that I should rename these 57 size icon to Icon.png and the 72 size one to Icon@2x.png. After renaming, it works.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I ran into this same problem using xCode 5 - all the icons are there and appear correctly on the corresponding devices, but the validation fails. After some experimentation, I found that the following steps will resolve the common causes:

**1) Ensure the correct filenames are used**

The legacy icons need to follow a specific naming scheme (for apps supporting iOS 6.x and lower):

```
 57 x  57 --> Icon.png        (iPhone)
114 x 114 --> Icon@2x.png     (iPhone Retina)
 72 x  72 --> Icon-72.png     (iPad)
144 x 144 --> Icon-72@2x.png  (iPad Retina)
```

Note that iPad icons are called `Icon-72`. `Icon~iPad`, which worked in the past, doesn’t work any more (at least, not for me - it generates the same error that you reported).

The naming scheme for icons needed in iOS 7 and later is:

```
120 x 120 --> Icon-60@2x.png  (iPhone Retina)
 76 x  76 --> Icon-76.png     (iPad)
152 x 152 --> Icon-76@2x.png  (iPad Retina)
```

The easiest way to update the names is to click on them in the file browser in xCode and rename them directly there.

*Source of filenames:* https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

**2) Check that the Project file has detected all the icons**

Click on your project file in xCode, and make sure the App Icons section has picked up each of the files. If not, manually select them. If you cannot select the icon file, it’s likely that the dimensions aren’t correct. You can check this by selecting the file in Finder, and pressing CMD-I to Get Information, and look at the dimensions under More Information.

**3) Make sure that the plist has the right info**

Click on your `ProjectName-Info.plist` file, and check the array under`CFBundleIcons~ipad/CFBundlePrimaryIcon/CFBundleIconFiles`. It should contain 4 entries: `Icon-72`, `Icon-72@2x`, and the names of your iOS7 icons. If there are any extra entries (e.g. for the old icon filenames), remove them by pressing the - button. If they stay there, validation will fail when it's unable to find the corresponding files.

---

After trying the above, you should be clear of the 3 common problems: incorrect filenames, missing files, and corrupted plist. Good luck!

Comment: Do you mean `144 x 144 --> Icon-72@2x` ?

Comment: Rename file of 144x144 as Icon-72@2x.png

Comment: Thanks npc & Hasanur for pointing that out! I’ve corrected the typo in the answer.

Comment: if someone still have problem: check warning section. some icon generator creates files with incorrect resolution, for ex `144x145` instead of  `144x144`. in this case you'll got `missing file` error when uploads application, but in xcode you will see `wrong resolution` warning.