# Application Loader error icon missing 57x57, 72x72

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to upload an app, but i am getting the error "icons missing 57x57, 72x72". Here are the slots I can see in Xcode.
[image]

Comment: this might help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173439/missing-required-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iphone]

Comment: I think, I follow the naming scheme, but I don't know where and how to add exactly these two icons.

Answer (score 1):

1) Ensure the correct filenames are used

The legacy icons need to follow a specific naming scheme (for apps supporting iOS 6.x and lower):

```
57 x  57 --> Icon.png        (iPhone)
114 x 114 --> Icon@2x.png     (iPhone Retina)
 72 x  72 --> Icon-72.png     (iPad)
144 x 144 --> Icon-72@2x.png  (iPad Retina)
```

Note that iPad icons are called Icon-72. Icon~iPad, which worked in the past, doesn’t work any more (at least, not for me - it generates the same error that you reported).

The naming scheme for icons needed in iOS 7 and later is:

```
120 x 120 --> Icon-60@2x.png  (iPhone Retina)
 76 x  76 --> Icon-76.png     (iPad)
152 x 152 --> Icon-76@2x.png  (iPad Retina)
```

If you still face problem you can either refer this [link here] or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph) or you can ask me the doubt. Thanks

Edit :- Thanks for accepting the answer. You can simply drag and drop the images over them to use them for specific size.