# Xcode - ITMS errors (90022, 90023)

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, plist, info.plist

I have been trying to upload my App to iTunes Connect so I can use it in testflight. I managed to do this earlier this year, but now I get the following errors:

```
ERROR ITMS-90022: Missing required icon file
ERROR ITMS-90023: Missing required icon file
```

As the error message say, I'm missing some icon files. I have tried to manually create the icons (before I've used Asset Catalog Creater), but I still get the errors. 
I than generated the icons again to see if it would solve some errors.

I have used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173439/missing-required-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iphone) to learn the probably something is wrong in my info.plist. I than used a [QA page from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) to manually add the icons with out the xcassets. Still with no luck.

I'm stuck at this point and was hoping someone here could help me solve this problem.

If you want to test it, my code is available on [Github](https://github.com/juleskreutzer/SMTE/tree/master/Price%20Calculator/Price%20Calculator)
Tried the above on Xcode 7.0.1 and Xcode 7.1 Beta 3

Screenshots:

[ITMS Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97OHL.png)

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rp2D.png)

[xcassets appicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soCsZ.png)

Comment: You cannot upload build using beta versions of Xcode, so skip checking on Xcode 7.1. Can you make a screenshot of your assets folder -> appicon? Blur the icons if you want.

Comment: @vive, the errors is the same on xcode 7.0.1 and xcode 7.1 beta 3. For the assest folder i think you need the last link in my post ("xcassets appicon"), or do you mean this: http://imgur.com/Axr4aTr

Comment: I know, just wanted to save your time trying on Xcode 7.1, so I've mentioned it won't work anyway, so don't try. I've downloaded your repo, and at first you should delete the `Images.xcassets`, as you don't use it. I don't think you should use Info.plist to do it manually, as it's huge work. Delete this key and delete `AppIcon` from your `Assets.xcassets`, then add it once again (so the Xcode manage the keys).

Comment: @Vive, Just did that, than did a clean build and rebuild but still got the same errors.

Comment: @Vive I solved my problem, see my answer to learn how I did this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve those errors by deleting the archive from the organizer view, than preforming a clean build and recreating the archive. At this time, i noticed that my app icon was also visible in de organizer view (it was the placeholder when you don't have an app icon before).

At this time, iTunesConnect says that my build is processing so it should be available soon.

Answer (score 3):

I think it was asking icon for iPad Pro which is 83.5@2x (167x167). I added this icon in my asset catalog and error disappeared.

Comment: I recently faced this issue too. Which Xcode version do you use? Mine 7.1.1 doesn't support 83.5@2x (167x167) images ((