# ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file"

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode7.3, application-loader

Hi i try to submit my app to iTunes connect but Application Loader displays the following errors:

> ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions supporting iPad Pro."

I really don't understand why i'm getting those error, all my images are in places, I use asset catalog and I never encountered the problem before.

[image: AppIcons in my Asset Catalog]

[image: attributes inspector]

If someone can help me,... thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please share what is selected in your attributes inspector for AppIcon? Please update screenshot.

Comment: follow instructions on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173439/missing-required-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iphone

Comment: @AmodGokhale thanks i've updated my post

Comment: looks correct to me. Can you please try to clean build project and try again?

Comment: What Xcode version are you using?

Comment: I am getting same problem, any luck ?

Comment: @Mansour,@arslan haktic I am getting same problem. Any work around?

Comment: i am getting same statutions. Have you any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problem Solved!

You have to make sure your image assets are members of your target.

- In the **Navigator** panel *(left)* select your image assets file e.g. "Images.xcassets"
- In the **Debug Area** *(big middle panel)* select the `catalog` in question e.g. "AppIcon"
- In the **Utility** panel *(right panel)* go down to "Target Membership" and make sure the checkmark is select for the desired target e.g. your app's name.

[image]